# how to divide huge text file into small in java

Tags: java, file

my app needs to read huge txt files like 10 GB in java.
i am so new to this area. so need your helps
app should divide this huge file into small sized txt files and then it must read one by one.
how can i do that ?
thanks

Comment: What sort of file it is? Can you arbitrarily decide the size of the files?

Comment: 100 pieces for example